# Calculate difference between 2 epoch times, large table, optimize having 3 indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table that represents packets from a traffic capture called PacketsByDirection (showing only relevant fields):

```
    FrameNumber FrameTimeEpoch         FlowID    Direction
    288        1430221042.150789000     29      Direction A
    289        1430221042.150922000     29      Direction B
```

Now, this table has around 2 million rows (packets) and what I need to calculate is, for each packet, the difference of time between him and the previous packet **with the same Direction and the same FlowID**

I have done this with this query, plus adding indexes to the previous table to make the query faster.

```
SELECT t1.FrameNumber, flowid, direction,
    FrameTimeEpoch - IFNULL((
                        SELECT MAX(FrameTimeEpoch)
                        FROM PacketsByDirection 
                        WHERE flowid = t1.flowid
                        AND Direction LIKE t1.Direction
                        AND FrameNumber < t1.FrameNumber)
                    ,FrameTimeEpoch) AS TimeFromLastPacketFromSameDirection
FROM PacketsByDirection AS t1
```

And the result is something like

```
FrameNumber        FlowID    Direction    TimeFromLastPacketFromSameDirection
        288          29     Direction A                   0
        289          29     Direction B                   0
        290          29     Direction A                   5.422
        291          29     Direction B                   4.356
        292          30     Direction A                   0
        293          30     Direction A                   1.302
```

And so on. Now, this query takes around 1 hour for 600k rows, and now I'm working with millions of rows so I don't even want to try it. Here is the "explain" output of the query right now (that's a lot of iterations):

[image]

So my question is, is there another more efficient way to do this?

Thanks

EDIT: Here is the definition of the table

```
CREATE TABLE `packetsbydirection` (
  `FrameNumber` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FrameTimeEpoch` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `IPSrc` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `TCPSrcPort` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UDPSrcport` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IPDst` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `TCPDstport` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UDPDstport` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IPLength` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `FlowID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Direction` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Index2` (`Direction`),
  KEY `Index3` (`FlowID`),
  KEY `Index4` (`FrameNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: A fine question! Please include the entire definition of your table. For queries at the volume of rows you describe, there aren't any irrelevant columns, or indexes.

Comment: Sure, I added it to the post

Comment: Why are you doing a `LIKE` to match `Direction`? Surely they need to be exactly the same value, so equals (=) would be more appropriate - `LIKE` _might_ not hurt the performance, but `=` is semantically better.

Comment: Yep, you are right, thanks. I just thought they were similar, or that that was the way to do with strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this could work at all, but maybe running numbers could be faster?

```
    SELECT
      FrameNumber,
      case when FlowID <> @currflow or Direction <> @currdir then @diff := 0 else @diff := FrameTimeEpoch - @epoch end as TimeFromLastPacketFromSameDirection
      , @currflow := FlowID, @currdir := Direction, @diff, @epoch := FrameTimeEpoch
    FROM
      packetsbydirection, (select @epoch := 0, @currflow :="", @currdir := "", @diff := 0) as tmp
    ORDER BY FlowID, Direction, FrameTimeEpoch
```

Comment: I was trying it! It does! And really fast, less than 20 seconds. I was trying to understand the query...didn't know I could do that in Mysql. Thank you very much, you saved my day!

Comment: Fantastic, glad it works for you. Doing aggregation on every row is expensive and should be avoided when working with large data set.

Comment: It's possible, but not certain, that you'll get even more improvement by creating a compound index on `(FlowID, Direction, FrameTimeEpoch, FrameNumber)`. The improvement would come from MySQL's ability to use that index to satisfy the query without actually sorting anything.

Comment: That also sounds good. I will try and notify the results. Thanks!